# Is harmonic distortion only a problem for the power company?

Tags: led, rectifier, led-driver, harmonics, total-harmonic-distortion

I know that harmonic distortion is a problem for the power company because it influences the power factor, but what about me as an end user?

In my situation I would use 9 drivers of 200W (230VAC/48VDC) for LED track-lights, though not under full load. The spec sheet states that when used for lighting (in Europe) they are not up to code with IEC61000-3-2.

Will these cause any problems in other electronic devices?

Comment: No. Only for the consumer. You always pay for "distortion".

Comment: At your power level I don’t think the effects of harmonic distortion will cause problems unless you specifically need to comply with the Euro regs. If you had 100’s of these lights, then it might be a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Harmonic distortion is just one of the various disturbances that affect both parties:

- Any disturbance in the *voltage* (caused by the supplier) is a problem for the consumer
- Any disturbance in the *current* (caused by the consumer) is a problem for the supplier

> Will these cause any problems in other electronic devices?

It's some times possible that one consumer device may have be a noticeable effect on other consumer devices in the same household. Typically, lights may flicker when a motor turns on (refrigerator, air conditioning).

Comment: But how would these problems translate in reality? Or how can I predict the possible effects?

Comment: See my edit, please.